# scipy interpolate gives unbounded value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a data set `data[xi,yi,zi]` I'd like to plot (with interpolation values).  With scipy.interpolate, everything looks almost perfect however the interpolation is generating some values beyond the bounds of the input data.  for example suppose `zi` is bound by `0 < zi < 1`, the rbf interpolatation seems to be returning interpolated values out of the bounds (e.g. `>1`); here my simplified attempt:

```
N=100
data=[xi yi zi]
xis = np.linspace(xi.min(), xi.max(), N)
yis = np.linspace(yi.min(), yi.max(), N)
XI, YI =  np.meshgrid(xis,yis)
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(xi, yi, zi, function='linear')
ZI=rbf(XI,YI)
print ZI.max()
->1.01357328514
```

Is there a way to pass limits to Rbf and let it know not to go past zi.max() and zi.min() ?

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example? `data=[xi yi zi]` isn't helping

Comment: Sorry I went to bed after posting.  Your solution below works well @Michelle, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation with radial basis functions may result in values above the maximum and below the minimum of the given data values. ([Illustration](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/how-radial-basis-functions-work.htm)). This is a mathematical feature of the method, one cannot pass in an option  to disable it. Two possible solutions:

- use [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to clip the interpolant between the min-max values of the data, when plotting it.
- use piecewise linear interpolation instead ([`scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html)), which is guaranteed to respect the minimum and maximum of data values.